# How to access recursive structure with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, recursion

I am getting a really strange error in my C program and therefore I need your help guys! So I have a recursive structure called path, where sometimes I store the address of the "parent" path in the structure field mother:

```
 typedef struct path{

  struct path* mother;
  struct path** children;
  int length;
  uint8_t* inf;
 } path;
```

So in my example I just generate one path like this:

```
  int child_num=2;
  int bytes=10;
  path* my_path=malloc(sizeof(path));
  if (path==NULL) throw error...

  my_path->inf=malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*bytes);
  memset(my_path->inf, 4, bytes);

  my_path->children=malloc(sizeof(path*)*child_num);

  for(int i=0; i<child_num; i++){
      my_path->children[i]->mother=my_path;
      my_path->children[i]->inf=malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*bytes);
      memset(my_path->children[i]->inf, 5, bytes);
  }
```

So now since I stored the link to the parent structure, I want to use another helping pointer to get access to its information:

```
  path* my_pointer=my_path->children[0]->mother;  //this is just for the example
```

So i checked the addresses and everything seems to be alright, but if I know use the pointer in another method, pointing to the field "inf", it works if I use the variable "path" so:

```
     method(path->inf, bytes);
```

it is fine, but as soon as I do:

```
    method(my_pointer->inf, bytes);
```

the method crashes at the marked line:

```
 void method(uint8_t* element, int bytes) {

     if (element==NULL) ... //<=== here it crashes
     //do something
```

}

I really dont get what I am doing wrong, I printed the addresses and everything seems to be good, even if I access a certain byte over the variable "my_pointer", so like

```
      my_pointer->inf[1]
```

it returns me the corresponding value, but in the separate method it doesnt work.

Comment: How did you determine that it crashes at `if (element == NULL)`? I suspect it's not really crashing there, as there's nothing there to cause a bad memory reference. The problem likely occurred right before that point, which is code that you're not showing. Perhaps something in one of the calls to `method`. Your first argument to `method` is either `path->inf` or `my_pointer->inf` or `my_path->...`. so check that `path`, `my_pointer`, and `my_path` are valid.

Comment: If `path` and `my_pointer` really do point at the same memory location, then `method(path->inf, bytes)` and `method(my_pointer->inf, bytes)` should produce exactly the same result. So my guess is that you've simplified the problem a little too much and accidentally left out some important detail. Can you write a short, complete, minimal program that reproduces the problem consistently?

Comment: The `sizeof(uint8_t)` is superfluous as it will always be `1`. (If `uint8_t` exists at all on the platform, it is going to be the same size as `unsigned char` and `sizeof(unsigned char)` is always `1` by definition.)

Comment: Yes indeed I tried to simplify the problem  I have in as less lines as possible, I will try to make it more complex to reproduce it but for now I dont see how.

I am sure it crashes at that line since I have for each crashing reason other "error messages"

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments indicate we can't exactly answer your question with the information provided, but we can point you in the right direction.

First, I noticed in your examples that you're using `path` as a variable name to a typedef'd `path` structure. You need to either be more verbose with your variable names or actually copy paste some code to make sure that we can look at the actual problem, because it could simply be an issue with naming.

All in all I think it would do you a world of good to employ a bit of code hygiene. Organize some of the functions you use for data structure overhead at file scope:

```
static int path_alloc(path* p);
static int path_alloc_kids(path* p, int num);

static int path_alloc(path* p) {
  if(p == NULL) { return -1; }

  p = (path*)malloc(sizeof(path));
  if(p == NULL) { return -2; }

  return 0;
}

static int path_alloc_kids(path* p, int num) {
  if(p == NULL || num <= 0) { return -1; }

  if(!path_alloc(p)) { /* Easier to read and understand, no error handling here to muddle things up */

    /* You don't actually need a path**, do you? Think of char *argv[] a.k.a. char **argv, is that what you're actually going for? */
    p->children = (path*)malloc(sizeof(path) * num);
    if(p->children == NULL) { return -2; }
    p->length = num;
  } else { return -1; } /* Simple */

  return 0;
}
```

This makes it a **LOT** easier to understand your code, which is the main issue with pointers. Add in some methods to free the allocated children and roots and you're set to use this path structure in a relatively abstracted way. You may want to consider using a `path` and a `path_node` in a linked-list fashion, that way you only allocate what you need.

```
struct spath_node; /* So it knows of itself */
typedef struct spath_node {
  struct spath_node *parent;
  struct spath_node *next;
  uint8_t *data;
  int data_size;
} path_node;
```

Then allocate by passing in a data size and parent, a `NULL` parent could mean it's a root node.

```
static int path_alloc_node(path_node *parent, int data_size, uint8_t *data);
```

This makes for relatively slow insert/traversal, but easier to understand where you went wrong.

**EDIT**: To be clear, this is how we would add children to the linked-list example:

```
static int path_alloc_node(path_node *parent, int data_size, uint8_t *data) {
  path_node *tmp;

  if(parent == NULL || data_size <= 0) { return -1; }
  if(parent->next != NULL) { return -3; }

  tmp = (path_node*)malloc(sizeof(path_node));
  if(tmp == NULL) { return -2; }
  else parent->next = tmp;

  if(data == NULL) { /* Assume the caller is requesting a new data block of the given size */
    data = (uint8_t*)malloc((size_t)data_size);
    if(data == NULL) { return -2; }
  }

  parent->next->data = data;
  parent->next->data_size = data_size;
  parent->next->next = NULL;
  parent->next->parent = parent;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Ian Abbott: Very true, this could make a bit of a difference since `sizeof()` is no longer done at compile time.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the code cleaning. 
but I have a question about your code, here I dont really get this linked-list thing, so you are declaring a struct spath_node to be a path_node?  
And possible "children" would then be stored in the pointer *next ? 
But how does this have still the recursion nature? I dont see how I could from "next" allocate more children

Comment: Another question I just noticed: I thought casting a pointer to a type is not necessary any more?

Comment: I was talking about a linked list because it's linear in progression and easier to understand. If you're good with that, then the multi-tree structure you have in your code makes a bit more sense. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) for a bit on linked-lists specifically.

As far as casting a pointer to a type, it's habit. Kind of like checking for NULL. lol